# changing root: No input file specified

Tags: magento2

I'm using Apache 2.4 server from Godaddy.

However I want to change the root of my domain to be pub instead of public_html.

I've follow the method in the following link :

https://webfiredesigns.ca/blog/how-change-documentroot-whmcpanel

After that I put following command :

bin/magento deploy:mode:setSmiley Tongueroduction

according to following instructions :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

My problem is now when I refresh my website the following error appear :

No input file specified.

Is there anything else should to be done ?

Looking forward for your kind assist.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Execute this command bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
Instead of bin/magento deploy:mode:setSmiley Tongueroduction

After clean the cache.
```

Comment: Hi dear, still not working

Answer (score 0):

It's solved after update doc root of PHP-FPM file according to following link:
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4403256459543-How-to-update-the-PHP-FPM-document-root-for-the-primary-domain